# Using BEM modifier classes

Tags: css, sass, bem

Recently I am combing through old projects trying to clean things up a bit. One place of concern is the CSS.

Given this, I thought I'd give BEM a go in order to tidy up a bit.

One bunch of style declarations I found was this:

```
#news-grid {
    .article {
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        border: none;

        .article-featured-image-box {
            position: relative;

            .featured-image {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }

            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            p {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .article-meta-information {
            color: #cacacd;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: $balto-font;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .article-content {
            padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            background-color: $white;
        }

        .article-title {
            font-family: $circular-font;
            color: $navy;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            word-wrap: break-word;

            a {
                color: $navy;
            }
        }

        .article-body {
            line-height: 24px;
            font-family: $balto-font;
            font-size: $body-text;
            font-weight: 300;

            p {
                line-height: 24px;
                font-family: $balto-font;
                color: $slate;
                font-size: $body-text;
                font-weight: 300;
                word-wrap: break-word;

                a {
                    color: $bright-blue;
                }
            }

            a {
                color: $bright-blue;
            }

            .article-excerpt p {
                line-height: 24px;
                font-family: $circular-font;
                color: $navy;
                font-size: 21px;
                font-weight: 500;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        }

        .article-footer {
            padding-top: 15px;
            border-top: 1px solid $grey-1;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .interactions-panel {
            width: auto;
            float: right;
        }

        .sticker {
            background-color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #282C35;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
        }

        /* Dark theme */
        &.dark {
            .article-title {
                a {
                    color: $bright-blue;
                }
            }

            .article-content {
                background-color: $slate;

                .article-body {
                    p {
                        color: $white;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Tweet theme */
        &.tweet {
            .featured-image {
                margin-bottom: -10px;
            }

            .twitter-title {
                color: #eee;
                font-size: 16px;
                padding: 25px 0 10px 0;

                a {
                    color: inherit;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }
            }

            .sticker-twitter {
                background: $navy;

                .icon-twitter {
                    .fa-twitter {
                        color: $bright-blue;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        line-height: 45px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
                }
            }

            .article-content {
                background-color: $bright-blue;

                .article-body {
                    p {
                        color: $white;
                        font-weight: $bold;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Facebook Theme */
        &.facebook {
            .facebook-title {
                color: #eee;
                font-size: 16px;
                padding: 25px 0 10px 0;

                a {
                    color: inherit;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }
            }

            .sticker-facebook {
                background: $bright-blue;

                .icon-facebook {
                    .fa-facebook {
                        color: $white;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        line-height: 45px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
                }
            }

            .article-content {
                background-color: $navy;

                .article-body {
                    p {
                        color: $white;
                        font-weight: $bold;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Vimeo Theme */
        &.vimeo {
            background: $grey-4;

            .vimeo-title {
                padding: 0;
                font-family: "CircularStd";
                color: #eee;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: 500;
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                word-wrap: break-word;

                a {
                    color: inherit;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }
            }

            .sticker-vimeo {
                background: $bright-blue;
                z-index: 1;

                .icon-vimeo {
                    .fa-vimeo-v {
                        color: $white;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        line-height: 45px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
                }
            }

            iframe {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .article-content {
                background: transparent;

                .article-body {
                    p {
                        color: $white;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there's a lot of repetition in order to restyle for different post types.

With BEM you suppose to have a block level elements, then elements that make up that block. Given this, I have the following:

```
.article-post-card {
    &__article-featured-image-box {
        position: relative;
    }

    &__featured-image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    &__content {
        padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    &__meta {
        color: #cacacd;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: "Balto";
        font-weight: 300;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    &__title {
        font-family: "CircularStd";
        color: #093875;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    &__excerpt {
        line-height: 24px;
        font-family: $circular-font;
        color: $navy;
        font-size: 21px;
        font-weight: 500;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    &__sticker {
        background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #282C35;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
    }
}
```

Following BEM convention how would I go about adding the type modifiers? Surely I would have to duplicate code?

Comment: What do you mean that you would have to duplicate your code?

Comment: I mean that the classes facebook, tweet and dark use identical style declarations, but just override specific elements.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

The Modifier in BEM is based on OOCSS concept. You will have to have both the classes in the DOM element.

While writing the scss you can go with the trivial way:

```
.article-post-card {
    &__title {
        font-family: "CircularStd";
        color: #093875;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        &--dark {
          color: red;
        }
    }
}
```